Induced norms and inequalities
Background:
There was a part of my professors notes that I didn't quite understand. This was the statement:
If a norm $|\cdot|$ is induced by a scalar product the following inequality is satisfied:
$$|x+y|^2+|x-y|^2=2|x|^2+2|y|^2, \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$$
Current understanding:
My understanding of this statement is that the inquality basically acts as a test for whether a norm is induced by a scalar product. If the norm satisfies the inequality then it is induced by some scalar product. There are norms for example the infinity/maximum norm that do not satisfy it e.g. $x=(1,1,0,...,0)$ and $y=(-1,1,0,...,0)$, which means the infinity/maximum norm is not induced by a scalar product.
Question:

How do I prove this?
Let's say there is a norm that satisfies the inequality. Would it be possible to recover the scalar product that it is induced by?
Are there vector spaces where all norms are induced?


Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity#:~:text=In%20linear%20algebra%2C%20a%20branch,of%20a%20normed%20vector%20space.
